# Any way to fix chromium hang that eats up all mouse clicks?

Tags: linux, chrome, browser, amd, hang

So I have been running into this weird issue where Chromium would hang, and pretty much lock out mouse clicks. The mouse can still move, I can navigate using my keyboard all non-chromium windows like alt+tab and etc. But I can't click focus on any window with the mouse.

If I kill chromium process, things go back to normal.

I have experienced this issue on both Mate Linux Mint 19.3 (kernel 5.4) and on KDE OpenSuse 15.2 (kernel 5.13), and on different computers using different mice (both usb and wireless).

Only thing in common with the hangs I have seen is:

1. All of them are on X11 (so no wayland)
2. Computers have AMD gpus, up to 6-7 years apart
3. Most of the time, it tends to happen when the mouse hovers over a tab and the tooltip shows up (but not always, just most of the time)

I have no way to replicate it though, it just happens every once in a while.

Anyone ever run into this issue and know how to fix it? (Please don't say use FireFox, I use it but I need both)

Thanks

Edit: I ran into the issue again, and it seems I don't need to kill the entire chrome but just the gpu process. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: For the time being and those having the same problem a temp solution is a custom shortcut to: ```pkill -f "chromium-browser --type=gpu-process"``` for ctrl+` (you may need to change chromium-browser to just chromium or chrome depending on your distribution) Still waiting on a more permanent solution if anyone has one.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I'm running Mint 20.3 with an AMD Radeon GPU. After I kill off the Chromium process that is of type `gpu-process`, the mouse comes back and I can click with it. I'm running kernel 5.4.0-113-generic and `amdgpu` driver (4.6 Mesa 21.2.6).

Comment: Same issue here. Very bizarre, the issue effects other applications as well. But if I close chrome it works normally again... Has anyone found an official bug report for this perhaps?